# Storing and retrieving shared preferences in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to store some settings using preferences I am using this code:

```
    SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                        pref.edit().putString("some settings", "lalal");
                        pref.edit().commit();
```

What i am doing wrong the file gets created but is empty

Answer (score 2):

**Try this code:**

```
SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit();
editor.putString("some settings", "lalal");
editor.commit();
```

**and get values using this code:**

```
SharedPreferences shf = getSharedPreferences("myCustomSharedPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
String strShPref = shf.getString("some settings", "");
```

Comment: Change the default to null and then have a if statement after checkinging if it != null which then would take the confusion out of getting nothing back, then you can do something with that.

Answer (score 1):

You've got 2 different editors for your prefs, first one adds the string, and second one commits empty changes, because you've changed another editor.

Change this:

```
   pref.edit().putString("some settings", "lalal");
   pref.edit().commit();
```

into this:

```
   pref.edit().putString("some settings", "lalal").commit();
```